# check id for xml

Tags: android, xml, if-statement

android studio xml. I am trying to check id but it is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@id/action_more" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <item  android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

Comment: `... but it is not working.` What should we understand by this assertion?

Answer (score 1):

It should be `@+id/action_more`, you're missing the **+**